# Ajax Handler 'onPagePosts' not found (October Newbie)

Tags: php, ajax

EDIT:
I know there is no code. Largely because I do not know where this code is!

I'm curious as to /where/ I should start looking (based on the stacktraces that I have) within the backend.

**I'm looking to solve my own problem, as it is, but am unsure where to begin.**

Anyone who knows where AJAX code is stored for October? Or a simple diagram of what is being called where? It's a great system, I am just a slow learner of machine languages.

EDIT2:
 Code present in the layouts that throws an error

```php
public function onPagePosts()
{
    $this->blogPosts->setProperty('pageNumber', post('page'));
    $this->pageCycle();
}
```

---

I have an AJAX script load more posts (sale items, articles, etc) as the user scrolls down the main page.

However, I did not build this (part of template) and am uncertain what exactly is wrong with the code. I have tried adding components to the proper pages, but am unsure where AJAX is calling from.

The code should be present on `/home`, and has been added to the default and home `.htm` and `.conf`.

The first few lines of the stacktrace (0-5) look like this:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined function is_countable() in /home/andmorew/public_html/modules/system/controllers/requestlogs/_referer_field.htm:1
Stack trace:
#0 /home/andmorew/public_html/modules/system/traits/ViewMaker.php(247): include()
#1 /home/andmorew/public_html/modules/system/traits/ViewMaker.php(97): Backend\Classes\Controller->makeFileContents('/home/andmorew/...', Array)
#2 /home/andmorew/public_html/modules/backend/widgets/form/partials/_field_partial.htm(7): Backend\Classes\Controller->makePartial('_referer_field....', Array)
#3 /home/andmorew/public_html/modules/system/traits/ViewMaker.php(247): include('/home/andmorew/...')
#4 /home/andmorew/public_html/modules/system/traits/ViewMaker.php(97): Backend\Classes\WidgetBase->makeFileContents('/home/andmorew/...', Array)
#5 /home/andmorew/public_html/modules/backend/widgets/Form.php(277): Backend\Classes\WidgetBase->makePartial('_field_partial....', Array)
```

The page should load the next "page" of results (viewed card-style by the user) but instead throws this error and does nothing.

Comment: _"However, I did not build this (part of template) and am uncertain what exactly is wrong with the code"_ - I didn't build it either... How do you expect to get any help without a [mcve]? Please read [ask]

Comment: so you need help without posting any code in here..